# Propel ORM Behavior for defining Parent Child relationships?

Tags: symfony, propel

I'm using Symfony2 with PropelBundle, and lets say I have the following schema:

```
<table name="person">
  <column name="id" type="INTEGER" primaryKey="true" autoIncrement="true" required="true"/>
  <column name="name" type="VARCHAR" size="100" required="true"/>
</table>
<table name="person_parent">
  <column name="person_id" type="INTEGER" primaryKey="true" required="true"/>
  <column name="parent_id" type="INTEGER" primaryKey="true" required="true"/>
</table>
```

Consider that a person can have many "Parents", just like a parent can have many child "Persons". Both of the columns in the "person_parent" table are foreign keys to the "person" table. Unlike for relationships like Book/Author where one can set isCrossRef="true" in the schema of table "book_author" to let Propel generate methods for directly getting/setting/adding book objects from an author class or viceversa, for Parent/Child relationships it is not possible to set isCrossRef="true" and thus not possible to get/set/add Parent Person objects directly from a "Person" Object. In other words it is not possible to do:

```
$person = new Person();
$person->setPersonParents($personCollection);
```

The method "setPersonParents()" to set all the parent "Person" objects of any given person is not available. However, for cross tables that do not reference to the same table like author_book, setting isCrossRef="true" allows for the following:

```
$author = new Author();
$author->setBooks($bookCollection);
```

With that in mind, it is also not possible to directly select a Person's "Parents" in a "New Person" Form...

For friend like relationships there is the [EqualNestBehavior](https://github.com/CraftyShadow/EqualNestBehavior), which allows for:

```
$person = new Person();
$person->setFriends($personCollection);
```

However, that behavior does not seem applicable to Parent/Child relationships since it does not care about hierarchy (if one tries to get the "Parents" of any given "Person", one gets all the "Childs" of that "Person" in addition to its "Parents"...). This is the behavior one would expect for "friend like" relationships, where a Friend of a Person is also that Person's Friend.

Is there a way to use the [EqualNestBehavior](https://github.com/CraftyShadow/EqualNestBehavior) for the Parent/Child case? or is there any other Propel behavior or method to handle this kind of relationships?

Comment: Please, attach examples of code and schema

Comment: What about using [inheritance](http://www.propelorm.org/documentation/09-inheritance.html)?

Comment: @thecatontheflat : I revised the problem statement to make it clear...

Comment: @WilliamDURAND : inheritance does not seem applicable since a Person who is a "Parent" can also be a child of another Person, thus I cannot create a "Child" class and "Parent" class since they both could refer to the same row...

Comment: You're right, I see your use case now.

Comment: Notice that I tried to use Propel methods like setPersonParentsRelatedByPersonId, while embedding a PersonParentType form in the PersonType form to be able to add 'PersonParentsRelatedByPersonId' objects, but the problem is that I don't know how to define the "person_id" in the PersonParentType form since "person_id" is not yet available for a new Person. Adding only a field for the "parent_id" in the PersonParentType results in a "Not null violation" because the "person_id" is missing. The issue is about how to handle many-to-many self-referencing relationships with Symfony2 forms. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about `EqualNestBehavior` but you could set up your workflow as following.

In your schema define FKs to `Person` table:

```
<table name="person">
    <column name="id" type="INTEGER" primaryKey="true" autoIncrement="true" required="true"/>
    <column name="name" type="VARCHAR" size="100" required="true"/>
</table>
<table name="person_parent">
    <column name="person_id" type="INTEGER" primaryKey="true" required="true"/>
    <column name="parent_id" type="INTEGER" primaryKey="true" required="true"/>
    <foreign-key foreignTable="person" name="p1" onDelete="CASCADE" onUpdate="CASCADE">
        <reference local="person_id" foreign="id"/>
    </foreign-key>
    <foreign-key foreignTable="person" name="p2" onDelete="CASCADE" onUpdate="CASCADE">
        <reference local="parent_id" foreign="id"/>
    </foreign-key>
</table>
```

After that, when you generate models - you'll get such methods as:

```
$person = new Person();
$person->getPersonParentsRelatedByParentId();
$person->setPersonParentsRelatedByParentId($personCollection);

$person->getPersonParentsRelatedByPersonId();
$person->setPersonParentsRelatedByPersonId($personCollection);
```

Setters accept `PropelCollection` as argument.

You just have to think about this situation not like "get parents" or "get children", but as about related elements.

Comment: I'm aware of the above methods generated by Propel. I'm actually using them in other contexts. The problem is that the above methods do not allow me to access a Parent Person Object directly from a "New Person Form". I would have to embed a collection of "person_parent" forms, each of which would then access the Parent Person object using a "model" field for "parent_id". But what about person_id? Moreover, in my use case I just want to pass a text field with a comma separated list of Parent Person Ids (I'm using jQuery autocomplete) though a "PersonstoIds" Data Transformer.

Comment: I tried to embed a PersonParentType form in the PersonType form to be able to add 'PersonParentsRelatedByPersonId' objects, but the problem is that I don't know how to define the "person_id" in the PersonParentType form since "person_id" is not yet available for a new Person. Adding only a field for the "parent_id" in the PersonParentType results in a "Not null violation" because the "person_id" is missing. The issue is about how to handle many-to-many self-referencing relationships with Symfony2 forms. Any ideas?

Comment: You could try to create new `Person()` where you need `person_id` - and bind it to form. Then you can also bind incoming properties from form to Person object without loosing existing id.

Comment: I created a new Person object and a new PersonParent object in the controller, then relate them through $person->getPersonParentsRelatedByPersonId()->append($personParent1); and then bind them to the form with $form = $this->createForm(new PersonType(), $person). However, the PersonParentType still needs a "person_id" but it is not assigned until saving to the database, so it does not work.. Did you have in mind something else?

Comment: Since the issue in this answer goes beyond the question about a dedicated Propel behavior, I created another question to discuss that issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12123517/symfony2-forms-how-to-deal-with-many-to-many-self-referencing-relationships-o